# Optimizing build time for multiple extjs applications

Tags: extjs

We have a modular monolith application, each module being an extjs app. Modules share alot of features / functionality, therefore the most of code is sitting in a common extjs package that gets imported into each module, the module themselves are relatively thin. We also provide an accessibility build, ie., everything is built at least twice (once with normal theme, once with high contrast), but for some apps more (some logic is managed through extjs macros to exclude / include different regions at build time).

The end result is agonizing build time. ~10 apps, each built at least twice, each build lasting just under 2 minutes. It's all because each app is built from scratch. Is there a straightforward means to build it together? So that instead of rebuilding extjs code / common package code / themes 10 times, it would be just built once and reused in build process of all apps?

This looks very relevant ["saving and restoring sets"](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/advanced_cmd/cmd_compiler_reference.html#advanced_cmd-_-cmd_compiler_reference_-_saving_and_restoring_sets) . But it seems to be some lower level feature, which would as far as I understand it come useful if we were reimplementing build process from scratch and tossing out app.json. Is there a clear way how to incorporate it into existing higher level features like `sencha app build`?

Answer (score 0):

You could go ahead and build the packages (if any) separated from the application, then drop the packages in the owning directories of the build. However, Sencha CMD and the way the class system and resolving the dependencies works makes it really hard to untangle the build process, so it's hard to give a general advice here.

You might want to look into the package loader of Ext JS and the "uses" configuration option for the app.json.